# Creating Columns From Stacked Data

Tags: sas

Piggy backing on a similar question I asked 
([Summing a Column By Group In a Dataset With Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57420269/summing-a-column-by-group-in-a-dataset-with-macros?noredirect=1#comment101331304_57420269))...

I have the following dataset:

```
  Month   Cost_Center      Account    Actual    Annual_Budget
  May      53410           Postage       23      134
  May      53420           Postage       7       238
  May      53430           Postage       98      743
  May      53440           Postage       0       417
  May      53710           Postage       102     562
  May      53410           Phone         63      137
  May      53420           Phone         103     909
  May      53430           Phone         90      763
  June     53410           Postage       13      134
  June     53420           Postage       0       238
  June     53430           Postage       48      743
  June     53440           Postage       0       417
  June     53710           Postage       92      562
  June     53410           Phone         73      137
  June     53420           Phone         103     909
  June     53430           Phone         90      763
```

I would like to "splice" it so each month has its own respective column for Actual while summing the numeric values by Account.

So for example, I want the output to look like the following:

```
 Account    May_Actual_Sum   June_Actual_Sum   Annual_Budget
 Postage       14562             37960            255251
 Phone         4564               2660            32241
```

The code below provided by a fellow user works great when not needing to further dis-aggregated by month; however, I'm not sure if it's possible to do so (I tired adding a 'by month clause' - didn't work).

```
 proc means data=Test N SUM NWAY STACKODS;
  class Account_Description;
  var Actual annual_budget;
  by month; 
  ods output summary = summary_stats1;
  output out = summary_stats2 N = SUM= / AUTONAME;

  data want;
  set summary_stats2;
  run;
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it for a report or for a dataset? I would recommend spliting budget and actual into different columns, but the rest shouldn't be changed IMO.  `Account Month Actual AnnualBudget` is likely the best overall structure.

Comment: @Reeza I do want to include budget, I forgot to remove it from the code (now changed) - not including it here for space purposes. I want to show month to month trends. Its for both a report and dataset.

Comment: In the data, is the `Annual_Budget` column actually an accounts annual budget apportionment for a given month/cost_center/account ? I ask because I don't understand why annual budget of May/53410/Postage is 134, and 234 for June/53410/Postage -- in other words, how does one find concordance between month and annual

Comment: @Richard Yes sorry, that annual budget should be the the same for each account regardless of month, this was a mistake on my end and will edit my post-sorry about the confusion!

Comment: @Richard so essentially, I want to sum the actual based on month and account but only sum the annual budget once since its constant and is the same regardless of month

Comment: So annual budget just becomes part of the BY group, along with ACCOUNT.  The MONTH variable is your CLASS variable.

Comment: Do you want a REPORT or an actual dataset?  How are you going to use a dataset in that horizontal form?

Comment: For month to month trends wouldn't that be a graph? Or use the LAG() or DIF() function to calculate month over month changes. If you want moving statistics, look into PROC EXPAND if you have SAS ETS. All will require you to keep the above data structure.

Comment: @Tom I want both a report and actual dataset. I want to crate a run rate variable for the accounts as the months accumulate so for example, take the average of the summed columns for May and June - divide by 2 then multiple by 12.

Comment: What makes you think you need your data to be wide to do that? Have you tried working with it in this form and it didn't work? It's totally possible to do it this way and pretty easily in fact. I suggest posting what you actually want, right now you've been giving us xy problems https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: @Reeza Apologies Simply put, I'm just looking to create a budget sheet like the one I stated above, where the Actual and Budget dollar amounts are summed by Account and Month. Each month has it's own datatable with the same exact variables (account, cost center, actual, budget, etc.), which I combined into one big long table (looks like the first table in my question above).

Comment: No, that's just a step in your process to do the next set of calculations and this is how you think you need to get there. Try PROC TRANSPOSE if you want a wide format. It's well documented with lots of examples. Here's a tutorial: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/sas/modules/how-to-reshape-data-long-to-wide-using-proc-transpose/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot think of a way to generate this report using just one PROC. You will need to do some post processing of `PROC MEANS` or `PROC SUMMARY` results to get to this:

```
proc means data=have SUM ;
  class Account month;
  var Actual annual_budget;
  output out = summary_stats SUM=;
run;

/* Look at summary_stats to understand it's structure here */
/* Otherwise you will not understand the following code */

proc sort data = summary_stats;
  where _type_ in (2,3);
  by account;
run;

data want;
  set summary_stats;
  by account ;

  retain May_Actual_Sum June_Actual_Sum   Annual_Budget_sum;
  if first.account then Annual_Budget_sum = Annual_Budget;
  else do;
     select(month);
        when ('May') May_Actual_Sum = actual;
        when ('June') June_Actual_Sum = actual;
        /* List other months also here. Can use some macros here to make the code compact and expandable for future enhancements */
    end;
  end;

  if last.account then output;
  keep account  May_Actual_Sum June_Actual_Sum   Annual_Budget_sum;

run;
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Use PROC MEANS to get summaries - same as last time. Please read up the documentation on PROC MEANS to understand how the CLASS statements works and how you can control the different levels of output.
2. Use PROC TRANSPOSE to flip the data wide. Since the budget amount is consistent across rows you'll be fine.

I'm guessing your next set of question will then be how to sort the columns correctly because your months won't sort and how to reference them dynamically to calculate the month to date changes. Which are some of the reasons why this data structure is not recommended.

```
    data have;
        input Month  $ Cost_Center  $    Account $   Actual Annual_Budget;
        cards;
      May      53410           Postage       23      134
      May      53420           Postage       7       238
      May      53430           Postage       98      743
      May      53440           Postage       0       417
      May      53710           Postage       102     562
      May      53410           Phone         63      137
      May      53420           Phone         103     909
      May      53430           Phone         90      763
      June     53410           Postage       13      134
      June     53420           Postage       0       238
      June     53430           Postage       48      743
      June     53440           Postage       0       417
      June     53710           Postage       92      562
      June     53410           Phone         73      137
      June     53420           Phone         103     909
      June     53430           Phone         90      763
      ;
        ;
        ;;
    run;

    *summarize;
    proc means data=have noprint nway;
        class account month;
        var actual annual_budget;
        output out=temp sum=actual_total budget_total;
    run;

    *transpose;
    proc transpose data=temp out=want prefix=Month_;
        by account budget_total;
        var actual_total;
        id month;
    run;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @reeza, I appreciate the help and will read up on PROC MEANS. I think I could potential produce individual tables by month and then just merge them back again based on ACCOUNT. I'll post the code if I can figure this out.

Comment: Doesn't scale. What happens next month when you have more records? Or next year when you have multiple years.