# Create a Count Where a String Appears More Than Once Per ID

Tags: sas

I have a following dataset that looks like:

```
  ID    Medication         Dose
  1          Aspirin        4
  1          Tylenol        7
  1          Aspirin        2   
  1          Ibuprofen      1
  2          Aspirin        6
  2          Aspirin        2
  2          Ibuprofen      6
  2          Tylenol        4
  3          Tylenol        3
  3          Tylenol        7
  3          Tylenol        2
```

I would like to develop a code that would identify patients who have been administered a medication more than once. So for example, ID 1 had Aspirin twice, ID 2 had Aspirin twice and ID 3 had Tylenol three times.

I could be wrong but I think the easiest way to do this would be to concatenate each ID based on Medication using a code similar to the one below; but I'm not quite sure what to do after that - is it possible to count if a string appears twice within a cell?

```
 Data ORD_V2;
 Length MEDs $300;
 do until (last.ID);
 SET ORD_V1;
 BY ID notsorted;
 MEDs=catx(',',MEDs, Medication);
 END;
 run;
```

I would like the output to look like the following:

```
  ID MEDICATION                    Aspirin2x   Tylenol2x     Ibuprofen2x  
  1  Aspirin, Tylenol , Aspirin         YES       NO             NO
  2  Ibuprofen, Aspirin, Aspirin        YES       NO             NO           
  3  Tylenol, Tylenol ,Tylenol          NO        YES            NO
```

The output of this table would then need to be used in an additional analysis data step.

Comment: Forgive me, but curiously, why do you want that format? Comma separated values within columns and using data elements as columns in wide format is rarely useful in data analytics.

Comment: What are your next steps? As we've mentioned before, wide datasets are rarely useful in the long run and this will very likely end up as an xy problem, as before.

Comment: Actually this is EXACTLY like your previous question, except you want counts instead of means. You can still use proc means because it does a count automatically though and use your dose as the statistics. PROC MEANS + PROC TRANSPOSE. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57432571/creating-columns-from-stacked-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either PROC FREQ or MEANS to get your counts and then use PROC TRANSPOSE. This is fully dynamic and will adapt to your data.

```
proc sort data=have;
by id medication;
run;

*Get counts of # of drugs;
proc means data=have noprint;
by ID Medication;
var dose;
output out=long N=Count SUM=Total_Dose;
run;

*transpose to a wide format;
proc transpose data=long out=wide prefix = Med_;
by ID;
ID Medication;
var Count;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the titled question, consider a running group count.

```
proc sort data=Medicine; 
    by ID Medication;
run;

*** FOR RUNNING COUNT;
data Medicine;
    set Medicine;
    by ID Medication;

    if first.Medication then count=1;
    else count + 1;
run;

proc sort data=Medicine; 
    by ID Medication descending count;
run;

*** FOR MAXIMUM COUNT;
data Medicine;  
    set Medicine;
    by ID Medication descending count;

    if first.Medication then max_count = count;
    retain max_count;
run;
```

[image: Table Output]

Comment: Note that `if first.ID then count=1; else ` is not needed since if an observation is the first for an ID it is by definition also the first for the first medication of that ID.

Comment: I don't understand why you could omit the retain statement for the variable Count. What am I missing?

Comment: Since this creates a running count, `retain` is not needed which keeps values across observations. Had we want a single count per group, `retain` would be needed. See extended answer for illustration.